# PCB power connector identification

Tags: power-supply, pcb, connector, identification

Can anyone identify the series of connector used for the AC input of this TDK MSA818 PSU from the late '80s?

The pin spacing is ~7.3mm (3.65mm if you count the missing pins) which doesn't match any JST series that I know of.   The pin size is ~1.1mm.

I'll be replacing it with a Meanwell RPT-60C, which uses a JST VH connector with 3.96mm spacing.

[image: TDK MSA818]

Comment: JST have a lot of those type connectors but they are 3.96-mm-pitch. If you are interested, you can check them from [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1790=21&sf=0&FV=fff802f3%2C1f940001%2C1f940005%2Cffe0013a%2C1bf80015%2C1bf80022%2C1bf80009%2C1f140000&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25).

Comment: @RohatKılıç yes, I already mention the JST VH range in the question.

Comment: oops, I didn't read the last sentence. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like HWS1884 on this site  https://www.peconnectors.com/friction-lock-hdrs-housings-page-4/

Or maybe these

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-1123724-3/A106609-ND/686936

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-1123722-5/A30504-ND/686669

Scroll down to Associated Products for the female pins to crimp on to the wires.

Comment: thanks, but 0.156" (3.96mm) is not 3.65mm

Comment: Let us know how you make out. I'm not finding any 3.65mm pitch connectors, doesn't seem to be anyone's standard size.    Can you pop the pins out of the housing and crimp new pins onto whatever you're going to use?

Comment: that's a possibility, yes, the female pins on the existing connector are slightly larger than the male pins on a JST VH plug, but hopefully not so large that they won't actually fit in the VH housing.